# How can I check timestamp when a kubernetes pod was added or removed from service (endpointslice)

Tags: kubernetes

How can I check timestamp when a kubernetes pod was added or removed from service (endpointslice)?
Maybe kubernetes leaves a log or event of it, but I can't find any documents regarding it.

My deployment replicas scale all the time, but I don't see any events regarding service or endpointslices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `kubectl get events` command to check the timestamp of the kubernetes pod.This will give you firstTimestamp and lastTimestamp for each event. You can request the output in yaml/json format if you want to check the event timestamps by running the below command:

```
kubectl get events -o yaml
```

You can also use a combination of customs columns and field selector by running the below command:

```
$ kubectl get events -o custom-columns=FirstSeen:.firstTimestamp,LastSeen:.lastTimestamp,Count:.count,From:.source.component,Type:.type,Reason:.reason,Message:.message \ --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Pod,involvedObject.name=my-pod
```